# Jquery do not load all css files on change

Tags: jquery, select, onchange

I have multiple branding css files, every one with different colors. Also I have a radio with these branding options. What I want is, when I change the value in radio, to load the specific css file and delete the last one. 
The issue is that only first time loaded css is showing the classes, when I change to second option, the classes do not load.

I have tried 2 different things, but with no success:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input:radio[name="category"]', function() {
    var $selected = $('input[name=category]:checked').val();
    $('link[title]').remove();
    if ( $(this).val() == $selected ) {
             $('head').prepend('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/branding/' + $selected + '.css" type="text/css" media="all" title= "' + $selected + '" />');
    }
});
```

also version 2:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input:radio[name="category"]', function() {
    var $selected = $('input[name=category]:checked').val();
    $('link[title]').remove();
    if ( $(this).val() == $selected ) {
                  function showmd( value ) { 
                    $( 'head' ).prepend('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/branding/' + $selected + '.css" type="text/css" media="all" title= "' + $selected + '" />');
                }
                $.get( $selected, function( data ) {
                    showmd( data );
                }, 'text');
        }
});
```

Always, the second css file appended do not show the classes.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

, and it looks like you are just adding a new stylesheet, do you also need to be removing the others that were added previously? I see that you remove all stylesheets with titles... but why would any stylesheet need a title attribute?

My suggestion is to add a class or an ID to the stylesheet you want to switch out and just change those particular attribute value.

So if this was in the document head:

```html
<link id="branding-stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" href="css/branding/example.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

```js
var $brandingStylesheet = $("#branding-stylesheet");
var $radios = $('input:radio[name="category"]');

$(document).on('change', $radios, function() {
    var val= $radios.filter(':checked').val();
    if (this.value  === val) {
        $brandingStylesheet.attr('href', "css/branding/" + val + ".css")
    }
});
```

Also, sometimes it might be a browser cache issue, and if so you might want to add a query string at the end of the URL to help break this.

```js
.attr('href', "css/branding/" + val + ".css?cachebreaker=" + Date.now())
```